# How to pass the output of one ARM template to the input parameter of the next ARM template in Continuous Deployment using azure devops pipeline?

Tags: devops, azure-resource-manager

I have a storageAccountResourceId ARM template that has the output section like this
below: This is my deploy.json

```
"outputs": {
        "storageAccountResourceId": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Resource Id of the Storage Account."
            }
        }
    }
```

For that I Created the Continuous Integration (CI) and Continuous Deployment (CD) in Azure DevOps pipeline, In CD I have used the PowerShell task to deploy the above ARM template. But I want to pass the output of this ARM template like "$(storageAccountResourceId)" to input parameter of the next ARM template in Continuous Deployment.

In know the above scenario can achieved using ARM outputs in between the two ARM task in Continuous Deployment. But I don’t want it because currently I am using the PowerShell task to deploy the ARM template.

This is my Pipeline.yaml

```
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - template: Modules/ARM/.global/PipelineTemplates/pipeline.jobs.deploy.yml@Azure-Services
    parameters:
      moduleName: StorageAccount
      modulePath: $(modulesPath)/StorageAccount
      deploymentBlocks:
      - path: $(parametersPath)/StorageAccount/parameters.json
        resourceGroupName: Poc-Bh-rg
        jobName: DeployStorageAccount
        expandDeploymentOutputAsVariables: true
      checkoutRepositories:
      - Azure-Services

  - template: /Modules/ARM/.global/PipelineTemplates/pipeline.jobs.deploy.yml@Azure-Services
    parameters:
      moduleName: StorageSyncService
      modulePath: $(modulesPath)/StorageSyncService
      deploymentBlocks:
      - path: $(parametersPath)/StorageSyncService/parameters.json
        resourceGroupName: Poc-Bh-rg
        jobName: DeployStorageSyncService
        parameters:
          storageAccountResourceId: ${{ variables.storageAccountResourceId }}
      checkoutRepositories:
      - Azure-Services
      dependsOn:
      - DeployStorageAccount
```

The storageAccountResourceId is printing in azure devops pipeline but how to i pass the that value to next ARM template deployment.

I used this option "expandDeploymentOutputAsVariables: true" also but this is not working

The azure devops next ARM deploy task is printing null value only.
below Image is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMStZ.png)

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve the above issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [nested or linked deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell). this can be done either with a inline/nested ARM (ARM inside an ARM) or linking to a "child" ARM from your main ARM

link example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      .... your other resources .........
    }
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "linkedTemplate",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'childARM.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "messageFromLinkedTemplate": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.storageName.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @viktorh, sharing your idea for my problem, i tried this but this is not working.

Comment: can you give me sample templates for dependents services like storage account is used in storage sync service or public IP address is used in load balancer